# Connect to Custom odoo Controller in android

Tags: java, android, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-mobile

I'm develop my own Odoo module to save many images at time in the server's file system instead of save as base64 images on the Database. Have a Controller wich recives images and deliver the image's filesystem path in json string's array. Why can reach this Controller from my Android in order to upload images from Android App? I using Odoo Mobile Framework to build the Android App. I start reading about Refrofit Android Lib but i think it can't works because Retrofit its to connect a RESTful services and Odoo uses XML-RPC?